# On which site should I ask about Android internals and developing custom ROMs based on AOSP?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

As far as I know there are good Google Groups dedicated to this topic, but I can't find a suitable Stack Exchange site to ask about this kind of topic.

- [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/): Its tour says:

  > Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for **users** of the Android operating system.

  I'm not an user! I'm developing AOSP operating systems.
- [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com): It's for App developers, not for AOSP custom ROM developers.

Comment: you can always request a site at [Area 51](area51.stackexchange.com/) if you feel that it would attract enough attention and have large enough scope

Answer (score 2):

On Android Enthusiasts Meta Stack Exchange, an FAQ reads

> [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/371/205764)

I personally recommend [XDA Developers Forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/) since it covers most kinds of developing for Android, while Stack Overflow orients programming. If you have an issue with coding during your ROM building, you can still come back to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com).

---

<sup>[I am an experienced user](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/205764/ibug) on Android Enthusiasts.</sup>